# How can something contain the Presence of the Almighty?

Tags: commentaries, theology, beis-hamikdash, mishkan-tabernacle

How could a building like the Mishkan or the Beit HaMikdash, or a natural phenomenom like a cloud (at Har Sinai) contain the Presence of the Almighty (Ubiquitious, the infinite volume; omnipotent; omnipresent; omniscient etc. G-d)?

Comment: Why do you think any of those things did contain God?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Kings.8.27?lang=bi

Comment: I don’t have time to write it up, but this is an answer: https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.95.6

Comment: @DoubleAA 1 Kings 8:12-13; Schneerson: “With the commandment to erect a Sanctuary, G-d gave the promise ‘I will dwell within’. That promise was fulfilled with the manifestation of G-ds Presence in the Sanctuary. The Divine Presence within our material world. [I.e. His immanent presence, rather than יהוה Himself].

Comment: @Levi Always include relevant information in the question please

Comment: I think it might have a been a spiritual manifestation of haShem. Keep in mind that in those times people were on a different level.

Comment: Why not? *Hayipale me'Hashem davar*?

Answer (score -1):

A possible (very common) explanation is "דברה התורה כלשון בנ"א" - Torah spoke in common expressions" (see [Wiki)](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D).

Namely, God prescribes to treat the Mishkan/the Temple AS IF it was filled with some Divine presence or was a high-rank dwelling. For example, the obligation to guard it AS IF it was a king's palace. And so Rambam rules ([Hilchot Bet Bechira](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Chosen_Temple.8.1?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi):

> שְׁמִירַת הַמִּקְדָּשׁ מִצְוַת עֲשֵׂה. וְאַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵין שָׁם פַּחַד מֵאוֹיְבִים וְלֹא מִלִּסְטִים. שֶׁאֵין שְׁמִירָתוֹ אֶלָּא כָּבוֹד לוֹ. אֵינוֹ דּוֹמֶה פַּלְטֵרִין שֶׁיֵּשׁ עָלָיו שׁוֹמְרִין לְפַלְטֵרִין שֶׁאֵין עָלָיו שׁוֹמְרִין:

> It is a biblical positive command to guard the sanctuary, even in the absence of fear of enemies or marauders, since by guarding the sanctuary honor is accorded to it. A palace that is attended by guards is quite unlike a palace that is not attended by guards.

Comment: It says the people saw the cloud. You're saying they treated it as if they saw the cloud?

Comment: @robev For those who believe that that cloud was Divine presence, I can't argue, but for those who believe in God's transcendence, it's just a mark - "worship me here".